# Youtube Data API からプレミア公開・予約されたライブ配信を判別する方法について

Tags: youtube-data-api

現在のYoutube Data APIで取得できるデータ上ではプレミア公開・予約されたライブ配信に対して同じ形式での表記(下に取得したデータがあります。)であり、またliveBroadcastContentの値もupcoming,none,live等同じ表記のため判別をつけることができないように思えます。

stackoverflow.com(jpではない方)でも同様の[質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54523948/how-to-identify-if-a-video-is-a-premiere-via-the-youtube-api)があり未だに解決されておらず、こちらでも質問をした次第です。

現在のAPIの仕様でプレミア公開・予約された判別が可能な方法をご存知のお方がもし居られましたら回答いただければ幸いです。

よろしくお願いします。

開始前のライブ配信

```
  "liveStreamingDetails": {
    "scheduledStartTime": "2020-10-30T12:00:00Z",
    "activeLiveChatId": "XXXXXXX"
  }
```

終了したライブ配信

```
  "liveStreamingDetails": {
    "actualStartTime": "2020-09-17T13:25:08Z",
    "actualEndTime": "2020-09-17T15:40:29Z"
  }
```

開始前のプレミア公開

```
  "liveStreamingDetails": {
    "scheduledStartTime": "2020-10-30T09:00:00Z",
    "activeLiveChatId": "XXXXXXX"
  }
```

終了したプレミア公開の動画

```
  "liveStreamingDetails": {
    "actualStartTime": "2020-10-19T12:00:13Z",
    "actualEndTime": "2020-10-19T12:04:25Z",
    "scheduledStartTime": "2020-10-19T12:00:00Z"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

liveBroadcastContentが'upcoming' 又は 'live' の場合、
status.uploadStatusの中身がライブ配信だと'uploaded'
プレミア公開だと'processed'になってますので
そこで判別が出来ることを発見しました。

配信終了後にはどちらも'processed'になってしまうので
配信終了後に判別する方法を探しております。

Comment: なるほど！
ありがとうございます。

自分は今、配信終了後の判別する方法に関しては最初に判別した状態をidと共に保存して、liveBroadcastContentで終了などの状態を取っています